# Check range date in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have in my database MySQL:

```
id | text | date_start          | date_stop
1  | aa   | 2011-12-17 10:45:00 | 2011-12-18 15:33:00
2  | aa   | 2011-12-18 19:11:44 | 2011-12-20 10:10:19
3  | aa   | 2011-12-21 15:14:00 | 2011-12-23 11:21:00
```

and i want check if example date is in database.
for example i im giving:

```
date_start: 2011-12-17 11:11:11 and date_stop 2011-12-18 16:11:11
```

this should return false.

```
date_start: 2011-12-20 11:11:11 and date_stop 2011-12-21 11:11:11
```

this should return true.

how can i make this? which query should be for this in SQL?

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to accomplish? I don't understand why the first example should return false and the second example returns true. Clearly explaining what you want to do and what you tried will increase the chances of useful answers!

Comment: i would like check this date - is this not reserved in database

Comment: Could you also explain *why* the second example should return true?  I'm looking at your table (which is not named) and I'm just not getting it.

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23 if the range overlaps a range in the database, then the range is unavailable, else it is available.

Comment: Sorry, but -1 because the question is just not clear and there's no attempt at a SQL query.  Maybe if he posted what he'd already tried, we'd have a better understanding of what he's trying to do.

Comment: See: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TestIfDateRangesOverlap for overlap testing logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WHERE start_date BETWEEN $start AND $end
OR end_date BETWEEN $start AND $end
OR ($start < start_date AND $end > end_date)
```

if you have a result, its false, else true.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)>0 FROM tbl WHERE date_start BETWEEN '2011-12-20 11:11:11' AND '2011-12-21 11:11:11'
```

I suppose that `date_start` should be between given dates.

Comment: it is possible that date start will not be in between any of the ranges, while the ranges still overlap. would have to check both start and end dates

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this is what you mean, but:

```
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password");
mysql_select_db("database", $link);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE date_start = '2011-12-17 11:11:11' AND date_stop = '2011-12-18 16:11:11'", $link);
$amount = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($amount > 0)
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: he wants to know if the range overlaps any of the ranges in the database.